# Why is nothing being logged?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, iis, microsoft.extensions.logging

I am currently having issues with viewing the logs my application should create.

I have using this https://elanderson.net/2019/12/log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core-3/ created a  middleware that should log request and responses.

I have then made a simple Asp.net core 6 application and deployed it to to IIS.

program. cs

```
using ReverseProxy.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapReverseProxy();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRequestResponseLogging();
app.Run();
```

with this web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="aspNetCore" />
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

middleware:

```
using Microsoft.IO;

namespace ReverseProxy.Middleware
{
    public class RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;

        public RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
                                        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory
                      .CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggerMiddleware>();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //code dealing with the request
            LogRequest(context);

            await _next(context);
            
            //code dealing with the response
            LogResponse(context);
        }


        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
            await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;
            await _next(context);
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _logger.LogDebug($"Http Response Information:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                                   $"Schema:{context.Request.Scheme} " +
                                   $"Host: {context.Request.Host} " +
                                   $"Path: {context.Request.Path} " +
                                   $"QueryString: {context.Request.QueryString} " +
                                   $"Response Body: {text}");
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }

        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
            _logger.LogDebug($"Http Request Information:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                                   $"Schema:{context.Request.Scheme} " +
                                   $"Host: {context.Request.Host} " +
                                   $"Path: {context.Request.Path} " +
                                   $"QueryString: {context.Request.QueryString} " +
                                   $"Request Body: {ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}");
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;
            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk,
                                                   0,
                                                   readChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

From what I can see is a logfile created in the expected folder, the content of the logfile though is empty? and none of the log statement I would expect is not there?

Why is the file empty?

Comment: _"Why is the file empty?"_ We cannot tell without seeing the middleware.

Comment: Added the middleware options. @Fildor

Comment: 1. Do _not_ use interpolated strings for logging. Better use structured logging. 2. You are logging in Debug Level. Is it enabled?

Comment: The order you add your middleware is important. Move `app.MapReverseProxy();` to be after `app.UseRequestResponseLogging();`

Comment: 3. You are calling `await _next(context);` twice!!

Comment: Also, it would be interesting, how you set up the File Logging. I cannot see any of that.

Comment: I have not set up anything specifc for file logging, the web.config should be setup to be printing to the log file?

and the logging level is set to information, so I would assume that debug level information should appear there?

Comment: Does your project work fine locally? Or the problem only occurs on iis.

Comment: The problem is both local and on iis. 
The webconfig forces the creation of an log file, but there is no content in it. 
I assume nothing is being written to it.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.